# Single developer releasing multiple apps

Tags: iphone, app-store

When a single developer releases multiple apps, do they register the apps under different company names?
What's the most iPhone apps released by a single developer that you know of?

Comment: Questions that are not directly related to programming should at least be marked as community wiki, otherwise your question will probably get closed.

Comment: Each company name will require corporate papers and $99 to register with Apple's developer program.  Unless you already own several companies, why would you add that legal expense?

Answer (score 1):

During your submission of the first app in app store, you have to enter your company name. It can be different from the name which is used to create the developer account. Once created, you can not change this company name, that is any future app from that developer account will have that company name.

This was the scenario at least at the start of this year. I don't know whether this policy is changed now (little possibility of changing).

Comment: So what do developers of multiple apps do? Do they always use the same company name, or are there some developers that use multiple company names?

Comment: There are lots of company that have multiple apps. And if someone is using more that one account, how can you be sure? That is after all dependent on the choice of the company. The bottom line is, you can have only one company name under a developer account and can have as many app as you want under that company name.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just wondering if developers go to the trouble to have multiple company names if they create apps that are drastically different. Like if they created a game and then they also created a business app. I noticed that usually company names seem to fit the app their making. Like if it's a game the company will have a name that sounds like it's a gaming company.

Comment: Some developers do own, or consult for, multiple incorporated entities in different businesses.

Answer (score 1):

I have at least 200+ apps in the store. Admittedly, most developers would refer to them as Shovelware. However, that is not my intent, and I go to great lengths to prevent that. As far as I know, Apple doesn't have a limit on the number of apps. Note though, that the latest Apple App Approval changes have a clause about developers spamming the store with similar apps. The practice is frowned upon. Also, all of our apps are under one company name.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Why don't you make one app with in-app purchase... I don't get the what's the advantage...

Comment: Spamming is not my intent. I ask this question because I have apps which are very different from each other and the company name might not look right with all of my apps. Are all your apps somewhat similar, or are they all very different? What is your company's name?

Comment: @gcamp: in-app purchase would make the app not useable offline, plus you couldn't customize the icon, name or search keywords for joe's barbershop, mary's pizza parlor, etc.